# Check if Class Implements a Specific Interface

Tags: actionscript-3, interface, implementation

in ActionScript 3.0, there are a few ways to check a class's extension.  for example, if i want to know of a custom class extends Sprite i could use the `is` operator:

`trace(MyClass is Sprite);`

or i could use `flash.utils.getQualifiedSuperclassName`:

```
trace(getQualifiedSuperclassName(MyClass));
```

i would like to accept a class as an argument and check to see if the passed class implements an certain interface.  is there an equally simple or common way to check if my custom class adheres to an interface?  perhaps something like:

`trace(MyClass implements IMyInterface);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just `trace(MyClass is IMyInterface);`?

Comment: oh!  haha.  i suppose i should have tried that before assuming it just wouldn't work.  thanks.

Comment: dont know how this is an accepted answer when it's wrong. This works for instances, not classes

Answer (score 4):

Use something like this function:

```
public function isImplementing( MyClass:Class, MyInterface:Class ):Boolean
{
    var description:XML = describeType( MyClass );
    var interfaceName:String = getQualifiedClassName( MyInterface );
    return Boolean( description.factory.implementsInterface.( @type == interfaceName ).length() != 0 );
}
```

This function returns true if the class is implementing the interface.

Comment: Allan's solution doesn't works for me. But this one does.