# Check if an AS3 class is Interface

Tags: actionscript-3, class, reflection, interface

How can I determinate if my [Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Class.html) object is an [Interface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f41.html) or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327495/check-if-class-implements-a-specific-interface

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
public function isInterface(claz:Class):Boolean
{
    return claz != Object && getQualifiedSuperclassName(claz) == null;
}
```